# Is it possible to get stories from facebook using API

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api

I'm looking to get the stories from facebook as shown in the image below

[image]

I can see the instagram offering story api here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-user/stories/ but is there similar resource to get the facebook stories instead?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Facebook GraphAPI does not provide a way to get Facebook Stories, only IG Stories are available (by the way only on business accounts)